# How to get the value from query string in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am passing the value of username into the query string but i am unable to get the value of the name in jquery.

this is my url

```
https://dev.hudpowerbid.com/front-end-pm/?fepaction=newmessageShami%20Kothari
```

**I want to get only Shami Kothari**

this is how i am attaching the name with the query string

```
var name= jQuery(this).parent().siblings(".htb200").html();
window.location.href ='https://example.com/front-end-pm/?fepaction=newmessage'+name;
```

this is how i am attaching name with url now i want to get this in jquery

this is how I am getting the value.

```
function getUrlVars() {
var url = 'https://example.com/front-end-pm/?fepaction=newmessage'+name;
var vars = {};
var hashes = url.split("?")[1];
var hash = hashes.split('&');

for (var i = 0; i < hash.length; i++) {
params=hash[i].split("=");
vars[params[0]] = params[1];
}
return vars;
}
```

Comment: @NickParson I think i need a separator in the url but when i am passing the & or ? separator i am getting syntax error

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are not assigning a key "name" to the value "Shami Kothari" in your query string, instead you are currently just appending it to the end of another value. To add the key "name" to your query string you can use `&` to specify another key-value pair:

```
window.location.href ='https://example.com/front-end-pm/?fepaction=newmessage&name='+name;
```

This way when you try and get name, it will look for the key "name" and retrieve the value, which is `"Shami Kothari"`

See working example below:

```js
function getUrlVars() {
  var name = "Shami Kothari";
  var url = 'https://example.com/front-end-pm/?fepaction=newmessage&name=' + name;
  var vars = {};
  var hashes = url.split("?")[1];
  var hash = hashes.split('&');

  for (var i = 0; i < hash.length; i++) {
    params = hash[i].split("=");
    vars[params[0]] = params[1];
  }
  return vars;
}

console.log(getUrlVars());
```

Comment: let me try with this

Comment: @TayyabGulsherVohra ok, hope it all goes well :)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: when i have used like this var hashes = url.split("&")[1];

Comment: @TayyabGulsherVohra did you see the code snippet I added to my answer? Don’t change anything in your code expect for adding the `“&name” + name` in

Comment: when i am adding &name it is navigating to different url thats why i have only attached with 'https://example.com/front-end-pm/?fepaction=newmessage&='+name;